# Reverse a word in the char array

Tags: c, strings, homework

I have to write a program that reads a word to the char array and next display it reversed. I must find best own optimal solution.

My solution of this exercise:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* reverse(char* str);

int main(void) {
    char word[50];
    printf("Podaj slowo: ");
    scanf("%s", word);
    printf("Odwrocone slowo: %s\n", reverse(word));
    return 0;
}

char* reverse(char *str) {
    char* reversed = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(str) + 1);
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = strlen(str) - 1; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
        reversed[j] = str[i];
    }
    reversed[j + 1] = '\0';
    return reversed;
}
```

I'm applying linear method, specifically iterating through every elements and store it in a new pointer array but I'm not sure if there is any better solution that I don't know. Can anyone add hints how can I optimize code and review it?

Comment: Use English, please. Most people here do not understand "Podaj słowo" and "Odwrócone słowo".

Comment: @CiaPan, the meaning is easily inferred.  I'm happy that the variable names are in English.

Answer (score 5):

#### Memory management

Right now, your code leaks memory--every time you call `reverse`, it allocates some memory, and none of your other code frees it again.

If all you're doing is reversing one string, then exiting, that's of little consequence--but if you try to use this in real code, leaking memory like this is generally unacceptable.

#### const correctness

Since you're not modifying the input string, you might as well use `const` in the function's signature:

```
char* reverse(char const * str);
```

#### Buffer overrun protection

Right now you have:

```
scanf("%s", word);
```

This is essentially equivalent to `gets(word);`. That is to say, it provides absolutely no protection against the user entering a string longer than you've provided space to store. When using `%s` with `scanf` (or cousins like `fscanf`, `sscanf`, etc.) you *need* to specify the maximum length:

```
scanf("%49s", word);
```

Alternatively, consider using `fgets`, which also requires you to specify the buffer size.

Note that there's a difference in the size you specify though. With `fgets`, you specify the size of the buffer, but with `scanf` you specify the number of characters it's allowed to read, which is one *less* than the size of the buffer itself. Also note that `fgets` normally retains the `\n` at the end of what was entered though (if you get data without a `\n` on the end, it means the buffer you supplied wasn't large enough to hold all the data that was entered).

#### Unnecessary Cast

When you allocate your memory:

```
char* reversed = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(str) + 1);
```

...you're currently casting the result of `malloc`. This is generally frowned upon by C programmers--it's unnecessary *and* it can cover up a bug of having failed to include the right header to declare/prototype `malloc` correctly.

```
char* reversed = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(str) + 1);
```

The cast is only necessary if you decide to write C that can also compile as C++. This tends to give the worst of both worlds, and should generally be avoided--if you're going to compile this as C++, use `std::string` and `std::reverse`.

#### Size Computation

When you allocate memory, you multiply the length by `sizeof(char)`, but `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1, so the multiplication accomplishes nothing.

Even if you decide to leave the multiplication in (since it is necessary for types other than `char`), I prefer to use code like this:

```
char* reversed = malloc(sizeof(*reversed) * strlen(str) + 1);
```

This has the advantage that when/if you (for example) decide to support wide characters, you can change it to something like:

```
wchar_t* reversed = malloc(sizeof(*reversed) * (wcslen(str) + 1));
```

...so the argument to `sizeof` doesn't need to change at all (and believe me--if you decide to do something like this, you have enough headaches to deal with, so even a small help will be welcome).

Answer (score 3):

Bug: off-by 1

```
// reversed[j + 1] = '\0';
reversed[j] = '\0';
```

Avoid mixing `int`/`size_t` types.

`size_t` and `int` have 1) different sign-ness and 2) potential far different positives ranges with `size_t` *usually* more than `int`.  `size_t` is the right-size type for array indexing and string lengths.

"how can I optimize code" --> No need to call `strlen()` twice.  Weak compilers will iterate the length of `str` on each call when only once is needed.

Check `malloc()` results

```
// Use size_t index for i, j 
char* reverse_alloc(const char *str) {
  size_t i = strlen(str);
  char* reversed = malloc(sizeof *reversed * (i + 1));

  if (reversed) {
    size_t j = 0;
    while (i > 0) {
      i--;
      reversed[j] = str[i]; 
      j++;
    }
    reversed[j] = '\0';
  }

  return reversed;
}
```

To reverse in place:

```
char* reverse_in_place(char *str) {
  size_t len = strlen(str);
  size_t i = 0;
  while (len > i) {
    char tmp = str[--len];
    str[len] = str[i];
    str[i++] = tmp;
  }
  return str;
}
```